# How to write do {} catch {} in Xcode unit test with 100% code coverage

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, code-coverage

I'm relatively new to unit testing and I'm hoping to achieve as close to 100% code coverage as possible, the do {} catch {} pattern is giving me grief trying to reach that goal.

Given this piece of code:

```
func testUrlRequest_WithAuthenticationNoToken_ExpectingAuthenticationFailure() {
        let mockController = MockAuthenticationController()
        mockController.token = nil
        Server.authenticationController = mockController
        do {
            _ = try Server.urlRequestWithHeaders(to: arbitraryEndpoint, excludeBearerToken: false)
            XCTFail("Expected throw when no token is present")
        } catch {
            XCTAssertEqual(error as? Server.Errors, .authenticationFailure)
        }
    }
```

The Server.urlRequestwithHeaders() method properly throws an error which gets caught by the catch {} block, but Xcode gives me this result for code coverage:

[image: xcode code coverage not 100%]

Seems it has two issues, first a warning that XCTFail() will never be executed (the dashed red warning), then a 0 red coverage matching the last "}" in the code, so I'm assuming it's some auto-generated return code that never gets executed.

Is there any way to properly tell Xcode that a code path is absolutely not expected to be taken and therefore ignore it as far as code coverage? Or is there a better pattern to follow when you need to unit test exception generation?

Comment: Coverage for the unit testing code is not valuable information, the coverage for the  tested code is the one that needs focus on.

Comment: I understand that, just wondering if there's a better way to write this...

Comment: You could try a `try?` :)

Comment: Yes but then you have nil but can't catch the actual exception generated to compare it.

Comment: Also note that it's impossible to simultaneously have coverage on both the try block and the catch one.

Comment: The fact that you are new to unit testing is obvious from the fact that you are trying to achieve almost 100% coverage. Don't do that. Coverage is just a statistic but it shouldn't affect how you write tests. Write tests for things that should be tested. Don't write one test for one functionality just to get coverage. It's better to write 10 tests for the same functionality even if your coverage won't increase or don't write a test at all if the functionality is too simple to be tested.

Comment: @Sulthan I think this is more meta than that, even. Instead of writing a test to ensure coverage of the product code, they are attempting to have every line of code written in a test be executed. This has no effect on the coverage of the product code, nor does it provide any benefit more than an academic exercise.

Comment: oh definitely academic; the whole unit testing is academic for me at this point :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, you should expect your unit test code to not have full coverage; especially for the `XCTFail` calls. The whole goal of the unit test is to *never hit that line*.

Even if you restructured your source to bring the `XCTFail` somewhere else, you're still intending to have it never executed. You could accomplish more code coverage by using `XCTAssertEqual` again.

```
func testUrlRequest_WithAuthenticationNoToken_ExpectingAuthenticationFailure() {
    let mockController = MockAuthenticationController()
    mockController.token = nil
    Server.authenticationController = mockController
    var failed = false
    do {
        _ = try Server.urlRequestWithHeaders(to: arbitraryEndpoint, excludeBearerToken: false)
    } catch {
        XCTAssertEqual(error as? Server.Errors, .authenticationFailure)
        failed = true
    }
    XCTAssertEqual(failed, true, "Expected throw when no token is present")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you'd have to set your 'let failed' to a 'var failed' but it makes sense :)